# Get the object with the max attribute's value in a list of objects

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, attributes

This is the code I written so far, and the point with the program is to read 20 people from a file and then assign them their attributes, then normalise their values from a input given by the user.

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrOne = ()
        self.attrTwo = ()
        self.attrThree = ()
        self.attrFour = ()
        self.attrFive= ()
        self.attrSix = ()
        self.attrSeven = ()
        self.attrEight = ()
        self.attrNine = ()


class Two:

    def __init__(self):
        self.allPersons = []

   def importFromList(self, filename): 
       file= open(filename, "rU")
       for line in file:
           partOfList = line.split()                        
           x = Partner() 
           x.attrOne = partOfList[0]
           x.attrTwo = partOfList[1]
           x.attrThree = partOfList[2]
           x.attrFour = partOfList[3]
           x.attrFive = partOfList[4]
           x.attrSix = partOfList[5]
           x.attrSeven = partOfList[6]
           x.attrEight= partOfList[7]
           x.attrNine = partOfList[8]
           self.addPerson(x)
        file.close()

def addPerson(self, x):
    self.allPersons.append(x)
```

What I wonder is how to loop through the attributes of the persons that is placed in allPersons list and then compare them against eachother to find out the max value. This is what I tried so far, but I can't get it to work

```
def getMaxValue(self): 
    o = One()
    for eachPartner in self.allPartners:
        maxValuesAttrOne = max(O.attrOne))
```

All help will be appreciated, and I'm open for new solutions, also I imagine the importFromList method is not the most effective one, so if you got any objections I'm willing to listen and learn!

Comment: Is there a reason you have 9 separate attributes named `attrOne` through `attrNine` instead of, say, a single attribute which is a list of 9 values, or a dict mapping 9 names to values?

Comment: Also, why does class `One` have 9 attributes all set to an empty tuple, while `Partner` has 9 attributes with the same names each set to a string? That seems like a recipe for confusion…

Comment: The attributes are definitions of a person, for example name, age and wealth. Renamned them before posting here. Is it better to do self.name = name instead of an empty tuple? 
Also how do you mean by having a dict mapping 9 names to values, we didn't dig to deep on how to use dictionaries in the course I did, but would love an example! @abarnert

Comment: If you actually have a name that you want to store, certainly it's better to store `self.name = name` instead of storing an empty tuple and then forgetting the name! But if you don't have a name, using `()` as an "initializing value" for an attribute meant to hold strings is very weird. Either don't initialize it at all (so there will be no `attrOne` attribute until you have a real value to store there—which is perfectly fine; you're allowed to add new attributes to objects after `__init__`), or initialize it to `''` or `None`.

Comment: As for the `dict` idea… if these are real attributes like `name` and `age`, you probably don't want to do that. When you have a bunch of attributes with names like `attrOne` and `attrTwo`, that implies that you're going to be writing code that tries to read an attribute chosen dynamically based on some index or something, and that's almost always a bad idea. It doesn't sound like you have any intention of doing anything like that. So, don't worry about that part.

Comment: One last question: In your real code, are `One` and `Partner` the same class, or one a base of the other, or something like that? Because here, they appear to be completely unrelated, and only coincidentally to have very similar attributes…

Comment: Yeah that's correct, must have missed it while writing the code here. In the real code the classes are Partner and Partners. Where partner store the attributes and Partners contains the code like importPartnersFromFile. The file im reading from contains 20 persons but they have the same kind of attributes, like name, age and so on. The point with the code im writing is to find a suitable partner for the user by comparing his choices to the attributes of the partners @abarnet

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`max()` takes a `key` parameter, a function that when passed one of the objects returns the value by which to compare them.

Use `operator.attrgetter()` to get that value:

```
from operator import attrgetter

max(self.allPartners, key=attrgetter('attrOne'))
```

This returns the matching object for which that attribute is the maximum. If you wanted to store just that maximum value itself, you have two options:

- Take the attribute from the returned object:

  ```
  max(self.allPartners, key=attrgetter('attrOne')).attrOne
  ```
- Pass just the attributes instead to `max()` with a generator expression:

  ```
  max(p.attrOne for p in self.allPartners)
  ```

If you find that you need to order the `One` classes in various directions by the same attribute again and again (to find the minimum, maximum, sort them, etc.) you may want to make your class *orderable* as well.

To do that, you'll need to implement *some* of the [basic customization hooks](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) Python will look for. With some extra trickery, you can get away with just the lower-than and equals operations, and by using the [`funtools.total_ordering` class decorator](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering):

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class One:
    # ...
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)): return NotImplemented
        return self.attrOne < other.attrOne

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)): return NotImplemented
        return self.attrOne == other.attrOne
```

Now your `One` class is orderable, entirely on the basis of `attrOne`; for the `max()` function, that means you can drop the `key` parameter altogether.

Comment: That's because there is an error in my answer; it should be `attrgetter` not `itemgetter`. Mea Culpa!

Comment: For the record, `itemgetter` is used for item access. `dictionary['somekey']` or `alist[1]` are examples of item access, and the `itemgetter` callable is used for those. Attribute access on the other hand is `someobject.attrOne`, and you'd use `attrgetter` for that. Trying to use `itemgetter` anyway would raise a `TypeError` because your class doesn't define a `__getitem__` method...

Comment: Tried the itemgetter solution, and I keep getting this error:

         maxValues = max(self.allPartners, key=itemgetter('age'))
    TypeError: 'Partner' object is not subscriptable

Please note that the names of the classes/methods may differ, sorry. Age is one of the attributes I want to get the max value from. If I understood objects correctly I should now have 20 (the number of persons in the file) partners placed in the allPartners list. For example writing in console.

    p = Partners()
    print (p.allPartners[0].age) gives the age of person 1.

Ps. Could only edit for 5 minutes.

Comment: Attrgetter stopped the error from coming! Though maxValues = max(self.allPartners, key=attrgetter('age')) prints out Tony, the name of person nr 5. While max(self.allPartners, key=attrgetter('wealth')) prints out Victor the name of person 3. Haha i feel so confused right now. :) @Martijn Pieters

Comment: That means that the value for `.age` is highest for `Tony`. If `.age` is a string, that might not be what you expected the highest value to be. `'10'` is lower than `'9'` because `1` comes before `9` in the ASCII standard. The age values would have to be integers to meet most peoples expectations of what would be the maximum. :-)

Comment: You are correct. Tony is indeed the oldest person. What it does right now is to print position [0] in Tonys line and the same for Victor and attribute ("wealth"). If I want maxValues to store the number instead, shall I change how my def __init__(): is written in class One(class Partner in the real program) as abarnert pointed out in the above comments?

This is how the partner Tony looks like in the text file
Tony    M  59  0,20  130 0,30 1200 0    0,9
M is gender, 59 is age and so on.

Comment: Added your options to my answer. :-)

Comment: As a comment to your edited text. ASCII valuing 10 lower than 9 explains some of the previous problems I've had :-) @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @MartijnPieters: One quick thing; ASCII is a bit misleading here; if the OP is using Python 2.x, it's that `1` comes before `9` in his system charset, which is probably not ASCII; if he's using Python 3.x, it's that `1` comes before `9` in Unicode. Fortunately, Unicode, and every important 8-bit charset that Python can handle properly, put the digits in the same order (and even the same position) as ASCII, but I don't think it should be necessary to know that to understand your answer.