# How to access specific attributes of objects in a list, as well as manipulating list based on those attributes?

Tags: python, list, object, attributes

Basically, I want to store objects with two attributes (name, score) in a list. From there I want to find the object in the list with the highest score, and be able to access the name of that object. So if 50 is determined to be the highest score in the list, I wan't to be able to see that this score belongs to "wages".

Here is my starting code where I create the objects with set attributes (for testing).

Storing the objects in the list works just fine, and I can access individual attributes in a for-loop (for i in a_list: print(i.score)) for example. But when it comes to accessing the maximum score and get the name associated with that object I am at a loss.

```
class Scoreboard:
    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = int(score)


t1 = Scoreboard("wages", 50)
t2 = Scoreboard("todo", 15)
t3 = Scoreboard("invoice", 36)

a_list = []

a_list.append(t1)
a_list.append(t2)
a_list.append(t3)
```

I tried using max() but that returns an error unless I only store the score value (ex. t1.score) in the list. If I do that I can't find a way to access the name attribute of that object.

Comment: Does it need to be a list or do dictionaries work also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the object with the max attribute's value in a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005172/get-the-object-with-the-max-attributes-value-in-a-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m = max(a_list, key=lambda s: s.score)
```

That should use the score attribute of each object in the list as the key when finding the max.

Answer (score 0):

Python has no way of knowing what Scoreboard is, and that it is supposed to use the `.score` attribute for calculating maxs or mins. As in the comments, a dictionary seems more appropriate. If you want to go on with classes you need to ask python to give you the `name` of the instance with `score` equal to `max(scores)`. Something like:

```
[(t.name, t.score) for t in a_list if t.score == max(t.score for t in a_list)]
>>[('wages', 50)]
```