# How to scan instances of a class to return the instance name with the highest specific attribute value PYTHON

Tags: python, class, object

```
class player:
    def __init__(self,targets,receptions,touchdowns):
        self.targets=targets
        self.receptions=receptions
        self.touchdowns=touchdowns
juliojones=player(100,80,8)
djmoore=player(80,60,6)
keenanallen=player(120,90,11)
```

How can I make this program look at all the instances of class player and return to me the name of the player with the most touchdowns?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Stack Overflow can help you, but you'll be significantly more likely to get helpful answers if you've demonstrated you've at least given it a try before posting here in accordance with the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: While what you're asking for is possible, it would be *much* simpler and more reliable for you to place each of these objects into an array, and iterate over the array. However it'll be *very* difficult for you to "*return [...] the name of the player with the most touchdowns*" as you've neglected to include such data in your `player` object model.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to programing and honestly do not even know where to begin so I have not tried anything, I just learned how to use init from youtube just now. What do you mean by I didnt include such data in the player object model. I put that for the instance of class everyone in that class has an attribute called touchdowns. Then i listed instances and specified their touchdowns. What am i missing? Thank you for your help and taking time out of your day.

Comment: check [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) and [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the object with the max attribute's value in a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005172/get-the-object-with-the-max-attributes-value-in-a-list-of-objects) It talks about a list, but `max` can also take multiple objects. So: `max(juliojones, djmoore, keenanallen, key=attrgetter('touchdowns'))`. However, it gets the object, not its name. Python names don't work like that. You should add a `name` parameter to the class.

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible approaches is below.

All class instances that are to be compared are first added to a collection.

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self,name, targets,receptions,touchdowns):
        self.name=name
        self.targets=targets
        self.receptions=receptions
        self.touchdowns=touchdowns

# Adding individual players to a list
players=[Player('juliojones',100,80,8), Player('djmoore',80,60,6), Player('keenanallen',120,90,11)]

# finding the player with maximum touchdowns
maxPlayer=max(players, key=lambda player: player.touchdowns)

# printing name only
print(maxPlayer.name)
```

`key` parameter in `max()` function defines *how* to compare objects (in your case by using `touchdowns` property)